# Creating Overlock-Seam

Tags: edit-mode

I would like to ask if anyone has any experience with building up textiles/seams. I am trying to create an overlock seam. Can anyone give me suggestions on how to build up a seam like the one in the picture as easily and quickly as possible?
Very dear greetings
Silvana

[image: Overlock-seam]

Comment: How close-up does the result need to be in your final image?

Comment: Hi, congrats on your first question here!  If my answer below didn't answer your question then some more detail could be helpful, such as end use (modeling/texturing for games has important differences from doing it for animation, for example), how closely this will be seen, etc.

Comment: It is for a picture rendering. I will render the whole product (1900mmx900mm) and some close ups. Therefore there will be some detail shots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“ . . . how to build up a seam like the one in the picture as easily and quickly as possible . . . ”  For ease and speed there are two main options:  1) a texture of an overlock seam can be used to sculpt a mesh, or 2) a simple model similiar to a half-cylinder with a tiled texture of an overlock seam.

For the sculpting option there are tutorials that can be searched for (the Blender Tutorial youtube channel has several recent vids that can help you decide if this solution will work for you and give you search terms for further research if needed: https://www.youtube.com/c/BlenderTutorialBT/videos ).

For the textured model option, first you need to find or make a grayscale tiled texture of an overlock seam.  The one I'm using in this example I made from the pic in your ask in [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/), and I've packed it into the blend file (link below).  This can be done better, searching for how to make tiled textures should give you more info.

Although the seam model can be any shape appropriate to an overlock seam, the UV map must be made straight over the texture used.  In this example I'm using a z-scaled torus section to demonstrate:

[image]

This material uses the same image texture for both the Principled BSDF Node's Base Color and Normal sockets, with a Mix RGB node on Overlay providing thread color:

[image]

The torus section has been duplicated and joined to show how the tiled image texture with the UVs layered provides a seamless (no pun intended) effect.  Here's the blend file:

[image]

Comment: Hello KickAir8p
Thank you very much for your perfect explanation. Worked out great. Best wishes

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Since I've answered your question please click the checkmark next to my answer.